# WSO2 API Manager Deployment Synchronization - SSLv3 Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting an error using subversion deployment synchronization in API Manager version 1.4 due to SSLv3 being disabled recently to close SSLv3 POODLE Vulnerability. I am using svnClientBundle-1.0.0.jar in order to connect to SVN. From my research this version is hard coded to use SSLv3. I have not located a solution to make this work. I have tried using the latest svnkit libraries by putting them in repository/components/lib and removing svnClientBundle-1.0.0.jar. This is not working.

Is there a patched version of svnClientBundle-1.0.0.jar that will work with TLS? Another solution?

Thanks in advance
Matt

Comment: Hi, I was able to get this working. For others who might be having the same issue, I deployed the latest svnkit libraries to my API Gateway and deployment synchronization is now working. I can connect via TLS.

Comment: Have you tried latest release of WSO2 API Manager?